# Topology exercise: how to prove this equivalent definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $F: X \rightarrow Y$ be a map between topological spaces. Prove that the following property is equivalent to continuity of $F$:

For every subset $A \subseteq X$, $F(\overline A) \subseteq  \overline {F( A)}$.

The definition of continuity is that the preimage of an open set is open.

$\\$

For one direction:
Assume continuity. $\Gamma_X$ is the set of all open sets in $X$.

$F(\overline A) \subseteq  \overline {F( A)}$

$\iff$  $\overline A \subseteq F^{-1} (\overline {F(A)})$

$\iff$ $X-\overline A  \supseteq  F^{-1}(Y-\overline{F(A)})$

$\iff$  $\cup \{Q | Q \in \Gamma_X, A \cap Q = \emptyset\} \supseteq F^{-1}(Y-\overline{F(A)}) $.

Since $F$ is continuous and $Y-\overline{F(A)} \in \Gamma_Y$, $$ F^{-1}(Y-\overline{F(A)}) \in \Gamma_X$$.

It can be proved that  $$ F^{-1}(Y-\overline{F(A)})\cap Q = \emptyset$$.

Thus the last statement is true.

---

QUESTION:

I don't know how to prove the other direction, i.e.

If $\forall A$, $\cup \{Q | Q \in \Gamma_X, A \cap Q = \emptyset\} \supseteq F^{-1}(Y-\overline{F(A)}) $,

then $F^{-1}(Y-\overline{F(A)}) \in \Gamma_X$.

If you can solve it, please tell me how you approach the problem instead of directly giving a solution.

Comment: Have you tried to prove using the equivalent definition of continuity described as convergence of sequences?

Comment: It's easier to us the equivalent "inverse image of closed is closed" characterisation. Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3557761/4280) e.g.